# React Native Animated - How do you disable default easing?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

How do you remove the default easing (easeInOut) that is applied to the Animated.timing function? For some reason, setting `ease: Easing.linear` does not remove the default easeInOut timing.

```
Animated.timing(this.state.positionX, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration:1000,
    ease: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
}),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your config object should read `easing` not `ease`.

```
Animated.timing(this.state.positionX, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 1000,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: true
});
```